# Bundler: always use latest revision of git branch in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, git, bundler, gemfile

I have a Gemfile with a private git repo in the following format:

`gem 'magic_beans', :git => "git@git.example.com:magic_beans.git', :branch => 'super_beans'`

When I `bundle install`, the Gemfile.lock locks it to a specific SHA revision.

Can I get bundler to always check and use the latest SHA commit and/or update the Gemfile.lock? Notice that when I push updates to the `super_beans` branch I am not modifying the gem version.

Ideally, every time I run `bundle` it would check upstream git repo for a newer SHA revision of the branch.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This isn't how bundler works.
The point is to allow seamless versioning of dependencies.
(particularly so you know exactly what version of the code is deployed at any given time).

If want the latest version, you should just run.

```
bundle update magic_beans
```

This is exactly the same functionality as if you just say

```
gem "rails"
```

I'd suggest though, if you have a range of specific things you want to update
then add a custom binary (say an executable file named `bundle_update`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
bundle install
bundle update magic_beans
```

Then just do a `./bundle_update` when you want to update these things.

Comment: If I change `:git` to use a `:path` instead, `bundle install` happily uses the newest SHA each time. I'll just keep using `bundle update`, but I don't think this is necessarily the ideal solution. After all, in my Gemfile I'm not scoping to a `:revision` but a `:branch`. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I know this is very old, but setting a `:path` always updates because it loads from a directory, not from a git repository or remote gem. `:path` is great for developing two projects together locally, but breaks down once you start collaborating.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `bundle update` to update all or specific gems to their latest available version, as stated in the [docs](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-update.1.html).

Would that help?

Comment: I guess if app and gem repos both belongs to you, and the gem undergoes lots of small changes, it is painful to also do a commit on the main app to point to the latest commit all the time.

Answer (score 1):

After searching through the documents I finally found the magic way to do this:

```bash
bundle update magic_beans --source magic_beans
```

That is to update the `magic_beans` gem only, but not to touch other locked gems. The doc about this is: http://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html

Comment: The first `magic_beans` is not necessary. You can just do `bundle update --source magic_beans`.

Answer (score 0):

delete .gemlock is what worked for me :/